# does a view embedded inside an horizontal scroll view cause infinite ondraw calls

Tags: android, view, ondraw

I have a cutom view which is embedded inside a horizontal scroll bar.I notice that my ondraw method is continously being called.Is it because of horizontal scroll bar?

here is my ondraw function:-

```
 @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"onDraw of Balls called");

      BallsOnDraw(canvas);

    }

     void BallsOnDraw(Canvas canvas)
     {

            canvas.drawLine(0, 240, 160, 0, mPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(160, 0, 320, 240, mPaint);

            TranslateAnimation mTrans = new TranslateAnimation(0, 320, 0,240);

            mTrans.setDuration(6000);
            SitoliaActivity.mBal.startAnimation(mTrans);


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal the Android system always calls onDraw() cause it's the method that the view gets drawn on the canvas http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)